# adb logcat print logs betwen two times

Tags: android, logging, adb

I have two logs I am interested in, that I have found like so:

```
09-13 13:11:23.311 14471 14491 D MyCustomTag: Log message 1
09-13 13:11:23.407 14471 14491 D MyCustomTag: Log message 2
```

I want to log **all** log messages between those 2 (i.e. all logs that ocurred between`13:11:23.311` and `13:11:23.407`. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give the Logs you're interest in a common TAG?

Comment: No, there is an error in my application, and I need to determine what is causing the error. If I could change the right logs so they have a common TAG then I wouldn't need the logs at all (because I'd know where the problem is)

Comment: Perhaps you should back off of this approach, and post your stacktrace instead.

Comment: Assuming you export your log to a txt file. do a multi-line regex for something unique in the first line, followed by anything, until something unique in the second line